# Automatic date change when editing any cell in a range

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I am struggling with this in Excel online and would like your help.

Is it possible to make a script that when editing any cell in the range A2:Q300 puts the date of when it was edited at the end of the row?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible currently with Office Scripts, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/633787/if-a-cell-or-range-value-changes-a-excel-office-sc.html).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for events. They are not currently supported however: "Office Scripts do not support workbook-level events. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/add-ins-differences

Answer (score 0):

If your *Last Modified*/timestamp column is R, try this:

```
=IF(CELL("row")=ROW(R2), NOW(), R2)
```

Drag down your R column as needed.

NOTE: You'll need to enable iterative calculations for formulas (Options -> Formulas).